# Run Magento and DB repair tool at the same time

Tags: database, mysql, database-update, repair-tool

I have a client who is intolerant of downtime but we need to run the DB Repair tool.

What are the ramifications of running the tool at the same time people are on the website?

I can run it from a non-public server but of course everything goes through the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions from Magento where to NOT do this.

I did test it on staging and it didn't seem to have an appreciable effect, but it is always better to be safe and run it while the site is shut down

Comment: I've done the same, no issues for my scenario.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the Magento database would handle commits well during the repair operation, you'd want an exclusive lock (single user mode type access) while doing this. InnoDB is transactional and fairly bullet proof, you just wouldn't want that one rollback triggered that messes things up. And then you create the very issue they were trying to avoid, downtime, and in a much longer timeframe.